# Running state machine on aiogram gives error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current_state'". Aiogram Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, aiogram

I am writing a telegram bot and using the aiogram library. In parallel with the launch of the bot, I run the "check_time" function.
I have an async function "check_time" which in an infinite loop calls another async function "intermediary". The last function is checked, and if it = true, then another function is called. In this method, I already start the state machine. When starting the state machine, an error occurs:

```
File "E:\Profile\Desktop\Projects\Python\Productivity control\src\handlers\analysis.py", line 12, in check_time
     await intermediate()
   File "E:\Profile\Desktop\Projects\Python\Productivity control\src\handlers\analysis.py", line 29, in intermediary
     await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
   File "E:\Profile\Desktop\Projects\Python\Productivity control\src\handlers\analysis.py", line 35, in analysis
     await Days.value_of_day.set()
   File "C:\Users\serg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\filters\state.py", line 56, in set
     state = Dispatcher.get_current().current_state()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current_state'
```

Code:

```
async def check_time():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        await intermediary()


async def intermediary():
    times = db.get_time_of_day()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    minute = str(now.minute)
    hour = str(now.hour)
    if len(str(now.minute)) == 1:
        minute = '0' + str(now.minute)
    if len(str(now.hour)) == 1:
        hour = '0' + str(hour)
    for time in times:
        if str(time[0]) == hour + minute:
            tasks = []
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(check_time()))
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(analysis(time[1])))
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print('all')


async def analysis(tg):
    await Days.value_of_day.set()
```

State machine class code:

```
class Days(StatesGroup):
    value_of_day = State()
```

db.py:

```
def get_time_of_day(self):
    with self.connection:
        time = self.cursor.execute(f"select time_of_day, tg_id from users").fetchall()
        return time
```

What could be the problem? Please help, I can't do anything...

Comment: I'm missing State, db and StatesGroup.

Comment: I have added the code of the "bd" file. State and StatesGroup I imported with the command
```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
```